# Why is there a Snapshot maximum on VM's using Hyper V?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, windows-server-2012

Hyper-V has a [50 snapshots max on a VM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj680093.aspx), I'm curios why.

Requirements and Limits for Virtual Machines and Hyper-V in Windows Server 2012R2

> Snapshots
>   50 - The actual number may be lower, depending on the available storage.
>   Each snapshot is stored as an .avhd file that consumes physical
>   storage.

I've never hit that number (nor will I) but I'm curios if there is a reason for that that number.

Comment: But why 50? (why not 32 ;) ) Why impose a limit if the system doesn't need one

Answer (score 1):

You start out with a virtual hard drive (VHD), and this first VHD is a fresh install of an operating system. When you create a snapshot it creates a few things from the VHD: a copy of the VM configuration in a .xml file, any save state files, and a differencing disk (.AVHD). The AVHD becomes the new, working disk for all writes, and this AVHD is the child of the working disk prior to the snapshot (in the case of your first snapshot, the parent disk is the VHD).

When a VM is created in a directory, two sub-directories are created - \Snapshots and \Virtual Machines. Snapshot is intially empty and Virtual Machines contains the original XML config file saved with a unique GUID (globally unique identifier) for the file name. A directory to create the save state files (.VSV) and memory files (.bin). The directory also uses the same GUID its name.

Write a few files, make a new snapshot, the process is repeated. You are now on your second snapshot, let's call it .AVHD(2) To reference recent changes to the original .VHD, your AVHD(2) looks at VHD(1) `(AVHD(1) is now known as VHD(1) that is Read-Only, parent to the current AVHD, and this process continues)` and reads those changes. To read changes OLDER than VHD(1), however, your current AVHD has to go back to the original VHD.

Let's make a change, take a snapshot, and make another change. We are now on our 50th snapshot, yay! This means to reference a change to a filesystem, we now need to look back at VHD(49). Is the change in VHD(49)? No. Let's look back again... 48, 47, 46..? No. To look up a change on an old disk, say VHD(7), you need to look through the other 43 snapshots first, because it doesn't know exactly where that change is. This is VERY resource intensive, and can make something as simple as a read very disk intensive - hence snapshots are not meant to be used on production machines (and various other reasons).

**TL;DR** When you create multiple snapshots a VM has to look through each snapshot first until it finds the one it is looking for. If you're on your 50th snapshot, it has to look through 49 other snapshots first to get to the original VHD. This becomes very inefficient very fast and slows disk speed to a crawl. I was not able to find a documented source for the 50 snaps, so it seems to be an arbitrary number for the sake of efficiency. [Source](http://blogs.technet.com/b/roblarson/archive/2008/04/26/virtual-machine-snapshots-with-hyper-v.aspx)

Comment: I appreciate the blog post you pasted here, but it doesn't answer the question of the 50 max so I can't mark it as the right answer. The blog post by Rob Larson explains what snapshots are. The link to where the documented max 50 is provided in the question, and here is a try in powershell: https://twitter.com/vNiklas/status/419175744992845824 . I'll digg around some more and see if I can find an answers. Thank you again.

Comment: @Isis Basically there isn't a reason according to all the sources I've checked. It's for efficiency sake. Also, that wasn't a blog post, I compiled a few sources into that. If I copied and pasted it there please point me to the source so I may meet my doppelganger.

Comment: It didn't answer the question, and I had no intention of offending you- I do however have follow the forum rules. If I had asked what snapshots are and how to create them I would have marked your answer as correct. I must have read the answer too fast because when I read the blog post you linked I found the two similar and thought the blog post was the source since you tagged it as 'source'- which is a common practice when one (as recommended by forum rules since links change) quotes sources. Apologies again if you were offended.

Comment: @Iris the tl;dr part says it seems to be arbitrary for the sake of efficiency - I'm still looking for an answer in other places, but that's all I can come up with for now. I'm sure you've done your research as well